# Pandas select by index and filter by boolean mask

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame()
test['1'] = [12,23,34, 45]
test['blah'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
test['a'] = [None, 1, 1, None]
```

I want to be able to select on this using both a boolean mask filtering and an index (that i define elsewhere), e.g.

```
test['a'] == 1  # filter

ind = pd.RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=2)  # pd index object
```

How can use them together? What I want to select (from index 2,4)

```
index   1       blah  a
2       34      c     1.0
```

I tried this but pandas doesn't understand how to use the index and boolean mask together

```
test[test.loc[ind,:] & test['a'] == 1] # Don't work
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html):

```
arr = np.intersect1d(test.index[test['a'].eq(1)], ind)
#alternative arr = set(test.index[test['a'].eq(1)]).intersection(ind) 

print(test.loc[arr, :])
    1 blah    a
2  34    c  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
test.loc[(test.index.isin(ind)) & (test['a'] == 1)]
```

Output:

```
    1 blah    a
2  34    c  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
test.loc[ind & test.index.where(test['a'] == 1)]
```